# auth0 demo app for fluttter native apps does not seem to work for me locally

Tags: flutter, auth0

As stated in the title i can not run the latest auth0 demo app on my android emulator when executing flutter run in the terminal. I followed every step for the quickstart sample app. Following error message shows up. I would be very thankful for any help I can get.

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform okio-jvm-3.5.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio-jvm:3.5.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/tony-andy.oehme/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4494a696d9b3b1721885311a5b1f734b/transformed/jetified-okio-jvm-3.5.0.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.20) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.jvm.environment=standard-jvm, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/tony-andy.oehme/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/62fc6279421758f70bc6149a8bcd9681/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6.1s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.            │
│ To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.      │
│ To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Flutter also states that the sample app uses some deprecated plugin management but I don't believe that it would stop the sample app from running.

```
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

e: file:///Users/tony-andy.oehme/Documents/programming/auth0-flutter-samples/sample/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/auth0/sample/MainActivity.kt:5:7 Redeclaration: MainActivity
e: file:///Users/tony-andy.oehme/Documents/programming/auth0-flutter-samples/sample/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/sample/MainActivity.kt:5:7 Redeclaration: MainActivity
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
```